# como mandar una variable a Bootstrap

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap

trato de presentar en un modal el resultado de una consulta dependiendo del Mes elegido....
desde una tabla:

Llamando a la función 'modal' con el dato del mes cuando se pulsa el mes correspondiente.

```
<table  border = 1 cellspacing = 0 cellpadding = 5   style='font-size:100%'>
<tr><td colsan='2'><p><p>Prevision de Gastos</p></td></tr>
<tr><td id='1' onclick='modal(1)'><P><P><B>ENERO</B><P></td><td align='right'>".$totalEnero."</td></tr>
<tr><td id='2' onclick='modal(2)'><P><P><B>FEBRERO</B><P></td><td align='right'>".$totalFebrero."</td></tr>

  </table>




> <script>      
function modal(ms){
> switch (ms) {   case 1:
>     $("#verEnero").modal("show");
>     break;    case 2:
>     $("#verFebrero").modal("show");
>     break;
>          } }
> 
>   </script>
```

como puedo enviar la variable al modal procesar los datos que se van a presentar, en lugar de crear un modal para cada mes....

el modal....:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="verEnero"  role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle"> Prevision mes: ENERO
 </h5>
        

        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="hidden" id="fechabd" name="fechabd" value="" >
        <?php
        
                
echo "<table id='tabla1' border = 1 cellspacing = 0 cellpadding = 5   style='font-size:100%'>";

echo "<hr>";
echo "<tr>"."<th width='70'>"."<font color='Blue' onclick='ordenar()'><b>Documento"."<th width='180' onclick='ordenar()'>"."<font color='Blue'><b>Proveedor"."<th align='right' width='80' onclick='ordenar()'>"."<font color='Blue'><b>Fecha Factura"."</th>"."<th><font color='Blue'>Fecha Pago"."</th>"."<th width='100' onclick='ordenar()'>"."<font color='Blue'><b>Importe"."</th>"."<th width='70'>"."<font color='Blue'><b>Iva"."</th>"."<th width='70'>"."<font color='Blue'><b>Total"."</th>";
echo $tb1;
echo "<tr>"."<td width='70' </td>"."<td width='180'>"."</td>"."<td width='80'></td>"."<td ></td>"."<td width='80'></td>"."<td width='80' align='right'><b>Total</b></td>"."<td bgcolor='#f08084' width='80' align='right'>".$totalEnero."</td>"."</tr>";

echo "</table>";

        ?>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Saludos....

Answer (score 2):

creo que lo mas sencillo seria utilizar un template en la funcion, pasando todo los argumentos que desees

```
function modal(mes,color){//pones los argumentos que quieras
    let temp = `
       <div>
           <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle"> Prevision mes:${mes}</h5>
       //asi vas creando la estructura del modal y utilizas ${}
       //para poner el nombre de la variable
       </div>
    `
```

y una sugerencia, identa correctamente tu código para que sea más fácil de leer